# How to get all selected Checkbox values into a sql query

Tags: sql-server, razor, checkbox, webmatrix, selectedvalue

I have a multiple filter query like this:
[image: pic]

I want to make the checkboxes be selected and then added to the following query:

```
var db = Database.Open("RMS") ;
var selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM RMS";
var formSSO = "";
var formCase_Status= "";
var fromDate = "";
var toDate = "";

   var SQLSELECT = "SELECT * FROM Admins WHERE Email = @0";
   var Email = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;  
   var data1 = db.QuerySingle(SQLSELECT, Email);
   var Name = data1.Name;  

    formSSO = Request.QueryString["formSSO"];
    formCase_Status = Request["formCase_Status[]"];
    fromDate = Request.QueryString["fromDate"];
    toDate = Request.QueryString["toDate"];

    selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM RMS WHERE Assigned_To = @4";

if(!Request.QueryString["formSSO"].IsEmpty() ) {
     selectCommand +=" AND SSO LIKE @0";
}

if(!Request.QueryString["formCase_Status"].IsEmpty() ) {
     selectCommand +=" AND Case_Status = @1";
}

if(!Request.QueryString["fromDate"].IsEmpty() ) {
     selectCommand +=" AND Created >= @2";
}


if(!Request.QueryString["toDate"].IsEmpty() ) {
     selectCommand +=" AND Created <= @3";
}
```

I can get it working if only one checkbox is selected but my main point is to allow multiple checkboxes to be checked. How can I do this either with JS or Jquery I have tried answers on other qts but they don't quite go with what I am doing. I don't want an alert but a way that I can call all checked values in the select statement.

This is the checkbox:

```
<li class="form-line form-line-column" id="id_20">
<label class="form-label-top" id="label_20" for="input_20"> Status </label>
<div id="cid_20" class="form-input-wide">
<input type="checkbox" checked="@(Request["formCase_Status[]"] == "In Progress")" name="formCase_Status[]" value="In Progress"> In Progress<br>
<input type="checkbox" checked="@(Request["formCase_Status[]"] == "Pending")" name="formCase_Status[]" value="Pending"> Pending<br>
<input type="checkbox" checked="@(Request["formCase_Status[]"] == "Closed")" name="formCase_Status[]" value="Closed"> Closed<br>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: I don't know that it is possible to answer this question correctly without knowing how your database is setup to read/write the columns concerning the values from the checkboxes in question.  Since you can really only know whether the box was checked or not, you are working with true/false values. Stored in a database, this can be several `bit` type columns (one for each checkbox), or possibly some value (maybe int or nvarchar?) representing all the possible combinations of values for all checkboxes. Sorry if this is vague, but without knowing more about the values on the DB side...

Comment: ...I'm not sure what else I can say to help.